# How do I make transparency better

Tags: transparency

It's sort of a weird description, but none of the blending for the transparency in materials really work for me. The closest would be Alpha Hashed and it still has a lot of graininess in it. Is there any way I could make the transparency "softer"?
In any other programs transparency works normally, if you set it to 50% the object is 50% transparent, but that can't be done in Blender. Is there any way around it?
I'm using eevee.
[image: Where I'm at right now]

Comment: hello, transparency should work fine, could you show a screenshot or share one of your objects?

Comment: Which render engine? Also, a screenshot of the viewport and the node editor would be great.

Comment: I'll add edits for those questions right away. Using eevee

Comment: Maybe elaborate about why you don't want to use Alpha Blend, you won't have any grains with Alpha Blend. Also maybe what you need it to use some other shaders like Translucent or something else? Glass is limited in Eevee so it may not be the right node to use if you have a lot of glass objects.

Comment: Alpha Hash in Eevee is significantly affected by the number of samples set in your Render settings. Increase the samples and you should reduce the graininess of the Alpha Hash transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha hashed will randomly(or regularly) set pixels as opaque or transparent based on the alpha. This is a limitation of the way transparency in every rasterized render engine.

Engines get around it with anti aliasing and softening techniques in post processing.

To get hashed to look good in blender, you need to increase your samples, use some denoising and softening in the compositor / post process.

An alternative would be to forgo Z-dependent transparency and use an Add shader node instead of mix. This will remove the glitchiness of Alpha Blend

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

- add more subdivisions/faces on each object.
- enable shade smooth on each object.
- enable light refraction on each object.

maybe that makes the appearance more pleasing.

Comment: The question does not pertain to shading. OP's issue is with poor quality of Alpha interpolation using Alpha hashed, which they must use because they have multiple overlapping transparent objects.
Using refraction would mask out occluded objects that also have refraction enabled